# Blizzard's SystemCheck tool doesn't work

Tags: battle.net

I'm trying to use Blizzard's SystemCheck tool to opt-in for future Blizzard game betas.

When I run it I see a page with my system information, but when I click "send" I get the error:

> There was a problem sending your system information to Battle.net. Please check your internet connection, close all applications and try again. For further assistance, please visit Battle.net.

And in addition my browser opens on [this page](http://eu.blizzard.com/support/article.xml?locale=en_GB&articleId=26886), which looks like an attempt to send me to a support page further explaining the problem, but it's actually just an error page.

The specific tool I am using is named `SystemCheck_enUS.exe`, downloaded recently from [my personal account page on Battle.net](https://eu.battle.net/account/management/beta-profile.html). If it makes any difference, I'm running Windows 7 and I'm not located in North America.

Comment: Do you have a firewall and have you tried with it disabled?

Comment: The tool has worked fine for me in the past. This might be a better question to ask on Blizzard's tech support forums or on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com).

Comment: @Anna I think this definitely belongs here more than SuperUser. And I have more confidence in this site than in Blizzard's tech support :) but I'm also checking other places, of course, and I'll update here if I find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've re-downloaded the tool again (for the 20th time, more or less), and this time it worked, so problem solved. This might be related to me resetting the Battle.net language before downloading the tool this time, as explained in the bottom of the [troubleshooting page](http://us.blizzard.com/support/article.xml?locale=en_US&articleId=27089), but I can't be sure.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using "plus addressing" in your Battle.net email address, try taking it out. That's what worked for me. Until I made the change, I would get the same exact error as you.

**SystemCheck didn't work with:**

- dave+blizzard@example.com

**SystemCheck worked with:**

- dave@example.com

Answer (score 1):

Blizzard's [troubleshooting page](http://us.blizzard.com/support/article.xml?locale=en_US&articleId=27089) has this to say

> **Why is the Beta Opt-in application
>   giving me an error message when I try
>   to submit my information?**
>
> First, verify that you have a stable
>   internet connection when attempting to
>   access a website. If you are able to
>   access websites, you may have a
>   firewall preventing the information
>   from being sent to us.  Please make
>   sure there are no firewall(s) blocking
>   the opt-in application from sending us
>   your system information. Downloading a
>   fresh copy of the SystemCheck
>   application may be the answer if you
>   are still seeing a failure message
>   after verifying the connection is
>   stable.